# Animation in a Toplevel Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, animation

for a project, i need to create an animation in a toplevel window. I want to have a first window with a button on it. When I click on it, I want to have a second window appearing with the animation. I searched among others posts but none solved this particular issue. Here is the code i created so far :

```
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as Tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import math

def open_animation_window():

    animation_window = Tk.Toplevel(root)
    animation_window.title("Animation")
    
    
    x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01) 
    fig = plt.Figure()
    
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=animation_window)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
    
    def animate(i):
        line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i / 10.0))  # update the data
        return line,
    
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200),fargs=(line, x), interval=25, blit=False)

# Fenêtre principale

root = Tk.Tk()
root.title("Fenêtre principale")

label = Tk.Label(root, text="SHM Simulation")
label.pack(pady=10)

# Bouton "GO" pour ouvrir la deuxième fenêtre

go_button = Tk.Button(root, text="GO", command=open_animation_window)
go_button.pack(pady=20)

Tk.mainloop()
```

The animation is not working, only the first frame appears (which is normal regardinging how it's done) and I don't know why.

The animation works properly on a single window. Thanks in adanvance.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I never tried to run FuncAnimation in Tkinter but `FuncAnimation` may have to run some loop to update data and this can make conflict with `mainloop` which also has to run at the same time. Usually `mainloop` waits for end of function to redraw elements in windows - so it redraw after finishing function. Maybe you need some `root.update()` in `animate` to force `tkinter` to redraw window. Eventually you could use `root.after(miliseconds, animate)` instead of `FuncAnimation`

Comment: did you run code in console/terminal to see error messages? I run it and it shows `UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything ...`

Comment: Thank you, it works using root.update(). I couldn't figure it out because without it would work once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

When I run code in console/terminal then I see error.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py:880: 
UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. 
This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation 
to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you output the Animation 
using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`.
  warnings.warn(
```

Problem is because animation is assigned to local variable `anim` in function and `tkinter` deletes this variable when it ends function.

You can assign it to global variable to keep it

```
def open_animation_window():
    global ani

    # ... rest ...
```

Or you can assign to some tkinter's widget which will be not deleted by `tkinter`

ie. to `TopLevel` window

```
    # ... rest ...

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(...)

    animation_window.ani = ani
```

---

There is another problem which generates error.

You define `FuncAnimation(..., fargs=(line, x))`
so you have to use `def animate(i, line, x):`

---

Full working code:

```
import math
import tkinter as Tk
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def open_animation_window():
    global ani
    
    animation_window = Tk.Toplevel(root)
    animation_window.title("Animation")
    
    x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01) 
    fig = plt.Figure()
    
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=animation_window)
    
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
    
    def animate(i, line, x):
        line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i / 10.0))  # update the data
        return line,
    
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), fargs=(line, x), interval=25, blit=False)

    #animation_window.ani = ani

# --- nain ---

# Fenêtre principale

root = Tk.Tk()
root.title("Fenêtre principale")

label = Tk.Label(root, text="SHM Simulation")
label.pack(pady=10)

# Bouton "GO" pour ouvrir la deuxième fenêtre

go_button = Tk.Button(root, text="GO", command=open_animation_window)
go_button.pack(pady=20)

Tk.mainloop()
```